# Cond (triad $) not working with a month condition in KDB Q

Tags: date, conditional-statements, kdb, q-query

This basic cond works :

`$[8i > 3i ; true;false]`

but this does not:

`$[mm$.z.d > 3i ; true;false]`

I don't understand why, since `mm$.z.d (current month)` is `8i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kdb reads right-to-left, thus it's comparing

```
.z.d>3i
```

before it ever gets to the month casting. You need to use parentheses to force the casting first

```
q)$[(`mm$.z.d) > 3i ;`true;`false]
`true
```

or better yet, refactor your statement to allow for the right-to-left

```
q)$[3i<`mm$.z.d;`true;`false]
`true
```